# Adding CSV files to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to loop through a bunch of .csv files and add them to a large dataframe, but I keep replacing the first row instead of adding them. Any help appreciated!

```
Z = 21

initial_csv_path = 'c:/1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(initial_csv_path)

csv_directory = 'c:/'
output_df = df

c=0
def loadnext(Tnum, csvpath, Sdf):
    
    Barnum_String = str(Tnum)
    nextfile = os.path.join(csvpath, Barnum_String + '.csv')
    new_data_df = pd.read_csv(nextfile)
    output_df = pd.concat([Sdf, new_data_df], ignore_index=True)
    return output_df


for x in range(3):
    Z = Z + 1
    if c == 0:
        z = loadnext(Z,csv_directory,df)
        c = c+1
    else:
        z = loadnext(Z,csv_directory,output_df)
        c = c+1

print(z)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an assignment issue.

Replace this line:

```
        z = loadnext(Z,csv_directory,output_df)
```

With this:

```
        z = loadnext(Z,csv_directory,z)
```

That should give you the fully concatenated result in `z`

Answer (score 0):

I usually start with an empty list and add the dataframes one by one to the list using list append.
Finally, I concatenate the list items using pandas concat.

---

```
import pandas as pd

lst = list()
for file in filenames:
    df_tmp = pd.read_csv(file)
    lst.append(df_tmp)

df = pd.concat(lst, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your csv-files match a specific pattern, you could use `glob` to fetch paths for all files you'll be reading:

```
import glob
file_paths = glob.glob("c:/*.csv")
```

Then you can simply read all the files in those paths and concatenate them with:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, file_paths), ignore_index=True)
```